# Git: Can a bare repo track some other non-git location? If so, how?

Tags: git

I have a bare repo that receives only pushes. When such pushes are made, I'd like for those changes to be reflected by the bare repo to another location (not a clone, just a static location with no .git folder).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. In order to do some action whenever someone pushes, create a [`post-receive` hook](http://schacon.github.com/git/githooks.html#post-receive). In order to get those changes from a bare repository into another directory (which is not a Git repository), you will need to create a [`git archive`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-archive.html) and expand it in the location that you want to update.

The `post-receive` hook receives on standard input a list of all refs that have been updated by a push as well as their old and new values, in the following format (where `SP` is a space character, `<old-value>` and `<new-value>` are revisions, and `<ref-name>` is the ref that was updated):

```
<old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name>
```

If you're only interested in mirroring `master` into your destination directory, you'll want to only execute your script if you see such a line.

For example, something like this would probably work (untested, so test this out on a location you don't care about before trusting it):

```
#!/bin/sh
while read old new ref; do
    if [ "$ref" = master ]; then
      git archive master | tar -x -C /path/to/expand/into
    fi
done
```

**edit**: Note that this has a fairly serious drawback; if you delete (or move) a file, this won't delete that file in the destination directory. One potential solution would be to add an `rm -rf /path/to/expand/into; mkdir /path/to/expand/into` before the archive line.

Comment: Nice. So does `git archive master` put the entire tree from master into an archive? If so, how would I just get the files that were updated from oldrev to newrev and not the whole entire file structure?

Comment: If there's a way to get only the modified/added files that's be great.

Comment: @trusktr Yes, `git archive master` just creates a tar archive, which you then expand into the location that you want to write them to. I recommend against just writing the changed files; ask yourself, what if for some reason, your script fails to run for one push? Those files won't get written, and you'll be out of sync if the next push involves different files. If you really want to write out just the changed files, you could start playing around with doing a `git diff $old $new | patch -p1 -d /path/to/expand/into`.

Comment: @trusktr But at that point, you really have to ask yourself "why am I trying to manually keep this git repo in sync with this directory, when that is exactly what Git itself is designed for?" You mentioned in another comment that you were concerned about the space of a second Git repository. If you know that you will always be keeping these two repositories in sync, you can use [`git clone -s`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-clone.html) when creating the second (non-bare) repository, which will mean that it will share its object space with the bare repo, taking up minimal additional space.

Comment: My repo has about 3,900 files. Would that be too much to archive for every push? Interesting. I've never used patch before. I just learnt all this git yesterday... In command that you've piped git diff to, how does patch know what to do?

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. so the repo cloned with `git clone -s` will look at all the stuff in the bare repo for reference?

Comment: I just looked at the man pages to see about the clone -s option. Seems to be exactly what I need! Why is this so difficult to find on google?

Comment: @trusktr Yes, if you clone a repo with `git clone -s`, it will have all of its own references, and information that tracks what it has checked out, but it will share the object store (files, directory listing, and revision data) with the other repo. You have to be careful with `git clone -s`, because if you cause objects to be unreachable in one repo, they may be garbage collected (deleted), but if they are still reachable from the other repo, that can cause problems. In your use case, however, when one repo is just being used to mirror another, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Brian.  But, what is the use case?  Why do you not want to do a clone if you want to track the changes?

Comment: I want to save space. Having the extra .git folder which is pretty much a duplicate of the bare repo makes the whole thing 50% larger. There are also other uses: the non-git location can be mapped to a network drive (so git thinks it is a local directory but really the files are going to a server via ftp).